# What are nmap's default timing values?

Tags: timing, nmap

I often use `nmap` to scan a network, and at times need to play with the scan timing. Unfortunately, my timing experiments have been mostly fruitless, probably because I'm using values that are completely out to lunch relative to what's needed.

It strikes me that if I started with `nmap`'s default values, adjusting from there, I'd have a lot more success. However, nowhere in the documentation (or the `nmap` command line) can I find a way to show what the default values are.

Here's a quick list from the command line help text of values which should have defaults:

```
--min-hostgroup/max-hostgroup <size>: Parallel host scan group sizes
--min-parallelism/max-parallelism <numprobes>: Probe parallelization
--min-rtt-timeout/max-rtt-timeout/initial-rtt-timeout <time>: Specifies
    probe round trip time.
--max-retries <tries>: Caps number of port scan probe retransmissions.
--host-timeout <time>: Give up on target after this long
--scan-delay/--max-scan-delay <time>: Adjust delay between probes
--min-rate <number>: Send packets no slower than <number> per second
--max-rate <number>: Send packets no faster than <number> per second
--ttl <val>: Set IP time-to-live field
--version-intensity <level>: Set from 0 (light) to 9 (try all probes)
```

... how can I find the defaults for these values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the followig values in the nmap-manual and nmap-book

https://nmap.org/book/performance-timing-templates.html

https://nmap.org/book/man-performance.html

---

--min-hostgroup/max-hostgroup

> min: 5 max: 1024

--min-parallelism/max-parallelism

> By default, Nmap calculates an ever-changing ideal parallelism based
>   on network performance

--min-rtt-timeout/max-rtt-timeout/initial-rtt-timeout

> min: 100 max: 10000 initial: 1000

--max-retries

> 10

--host-timeout

> 0

--scan-delay/--max-scan-delay

> initial: 0  max: 1000

--min-rate/ --max-rate

> no min-rate limit, no max-rate limit

--ttl

> 64

--version-intensity

> 7